# Render form elements from event subscriber using Symfony and Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, render, subscriber

I constantly get the error message from my Twig template, saying that:

> Neither the property "channel1s" nor one of the methods "channel1s()", "getchannel1s()"/"ischannel1s()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

I add the property channel1s within an event subscriber and am not quite sure whether this is the actual problem.

I've got a FormType which says

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

    $pathToAgencies = 'agencies';
    //
    $builder
    ->addEventSubscriber(new AddChannel1Subscriber($pathToAgencies))
    ->addEventSubscriber(new AddChannel3Subscriber($pathToAgencies))
    ->addEventSubscriber(new AddAgencySubscriber($pathToAgencies));
...
```

and in the EventSubscribers I add form elements. For example in the Channel1Subscriber:

```
  private function addChannel1Form($form, $channel1s = null) {
    $formOptions = array(
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Channel1',
      'property' => 'name',
      'label' => 'label.channel1s',
      'empty_value' => 'label.select_channel1s',
      'mapped' => false,
      'expanded' => false,
      'translation_domain' => 'UploadProfile',
      'multiple' => true,
      'required' => false,
      'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'channel1s'
      ),
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
                return $qb;
            },
    );

    if ($channel1s){
      $formOptions['data'] = $channel1s;
    }
    $form->add('channel1s', 'entity', $formOptions);
}


  public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $this->addChannel1Form($form);
    $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    $agency = $accessor->getValue($data, $this->pathToAgency);
    $channel1s = ($agency) ? $agency->getChannel3s()->getChannel1s() : null;
    $this->addChannel1Form($form, $channel1s);
  }
```

In my controller I create the form from the above FormType like that:

```
 $form = $this->createForm(UploadProfileType::class, $uploadprofile);
```

and in my Twig template it looks like that:

```
  {{ form_row(form.channel1s) }}
  {{ form_row(form.channel3s) }}
  {{ form_row(form.agencies) }}
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Here's the full code of one of the subscribers:

```
  <?php
    namespace DocumentBundle\Form\EventListener;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
...

    class AddChannel1Subscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface{
      private $pathToAgency;
      // private $em;
      public function __construct($pathToAgency) {
        $this->pathToAgency = $pathToAgency;
        // $this->em = $em;
      }
      public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
          // FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA  => 'preSetData',
          FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT    => 'preSubmit'
        );
      }
      private function addChannel1Form($form, $channel1s = null) {
        $formOptions = array(
          'class' => 'AppBundle:Channel1',
          'property' => 'name',
          'label' => 'label.channel1s',
          'empty_value' => 'label.select_channel1s',
          'mapped' => false,
          'expanded' => false,
          'translation_domain' => 'UploadProfile',
          'multiple' => true,
          'required' => false,
          'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'channel1s'
          ),
          'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
                    return $qb;
                },
        );

        if ($channel1s){
          $formOptions['data'] = $channel1s;
        }
        $form->add('channel1s', 'entity', $formOptions);
    }

      public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $this->addChannel1Form($form);
        $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        $agency = $accessor->getValue($data, $this->pathToAgency);
        $channel1s = ($agency) ? $agency->getChannel3s()->getChannel1s() : null;
        $this->addChannel1Form($form, $channel1s);
      }
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: I don't see the full code of your subscribers, but it seems like the fields are not added to the form.

Comment: I edit the post and add the whole code! I thought I add the fields with
**$form->add('channel1s', 'entity', $formOptions);**

Comment: Following your logic you add the form field on `PRE_SUBMIT` event, which means your form have this field only after it has been submitted.

Comment: So what would I have to change? I thought PRE would mean it is added before submitting?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to achieve :D But I'd suggest to read about [form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) carefully

Comment: So what I want to achieve is: having three dropdowns which are dependent on each other. so when selecting channel1s, the data for dropdown channel3s should change according to the selected channel1s and same thing for agencies and channel3s. I followed  http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/ instruction. And I'm on that topic for a week now but didn't get it working so far..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152786/discussion-between-sonja-and-sergekv).